# How to make a response data in array for Morris

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to create a data array from a return value of mysql. The raw data from mysql is :

```
$chart=Array ( 
[bd] => Array ( 
 [Eid] => 59100 
 [Mona] => 156050 
 [Nai] => 27750 
 [Nana] => 90680 
 [Pinya] => 9400 
 [Pok] => 43900 
 [Tunk] => 48600 
 [VEE] => 26800 
) 
[cp] => Array ( 
 [Eid] => 23650 
 [Mona] => 86760 
 [Nai] => 54160 
 [Nana] => 125300 
 [Pinya] => 63960 
 [Pok] => 59800 
 [Tunk] => 111260 
 [VEE] => 125460 
 ) 
 )
```

I want the final result comes in this format:

```
{
hotel: 'BD', 
  Eid:59100,
  Mona:156050, 
  Nai:27750,
  Nana:90680,  
  Pinya:9400,
  Pok:43900, 
  Tunk:48600, 
  VEE:26800, 
}...
```

So, I write :

```
foreach($chart as $hotel=>$rep){
    echo "{hotel:$hotel, $rep},";
}
```

And the result is:

```
{hotel:bd, Array},{hotel:cp, Array},{hotel:cs, Array},{hotel:km, Array}{hotel:nk, Array},
```

It is similar to what I want but how can I extract the `Array` into the format shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Code Works .

```
$finalArray = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($chart as $hotel=>$rep) {

    $finalArray[$i] = "{<br>hotel: $hotel,<br>";

    foreach($rep as $key=>$val) {
        $finalArray[$i] .= "$key:$val,<br>";
    }

    $finalArray[$i] .= "}<br>";     
    $i++;
}

$finalString = implode(",",$finalArray);
echo $finalString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
// set empty string
$sOutput = '';

// loop over each char data using its key as the hotel id/ref
foreach ($chart as $sHotelID => $aHotelData) {

    // if there is already output add a comma to the end
    if($sOutput != '') $sOutput .= ",";

    // add the opening brace and hotel info
    $sOutput .= "{hotel:".$sHotelID.",";

    // set empty string
    $sTempOutput = '';

    // loop over each hotel data entry storing into tempOutput
    foreach ($aHotelData as $sKey => $sValue) {

        if($sTempOutput != '') $sTempOutput .= ",";

        $sTempOutput .= $sKey.":".$sValue;

    }

    // assign the tempoutput to the main output
    $sOutput .= $sTempOutput."}";
}

var_export($sOutput);
```

This gives me:

```
{Eid:59100,Mona:156050,Nai:27750,Nana:90680,Pinya:9400,Pok:43900,Tunk:48600,VEE:26800}, 
{Eid:23650,Mona:86760,Nai:54160,Nana:125300,Pinya:63960,Pok:59800,Tunk:111260,VEE:125460}
```

Comment: Sorry, your answer returns the same thing as mine. `{hotel:bd,Eid:,},{hotel:cp,Eid:,},{hotel:cs,Eid:,},{hotel:km,Eid:,},{hotel:nh,Eid:,},{hotel:nk,Eid:,}`

Comment: Good try, but I also want the `hotel` value too :D